# AWSTATS - manual update error (permissions)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, awstats

```
Error: Couldn't open file "/var/www/awstats/awstats032014.site.net.tmp.9198" for write: Permission denied 

Setup ('/etc/awstats/awstats.site.net.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).
```

I get this error when manual trying to update awstats (via the browser link). I have set the folder permissions of /var/www/awstats/ to 775 and still get the error.

If I create a new file on that folder the default permission setting set the permissions to 774 which should work.

Comment: The Unix permissions model includes *users* and *groups* which you have omitted from your question.  Without knowing what user and group the file belongs to, only the 5 in the permissions 775 has any meaning to us.  The directory, the file itself and the process attempting to access the file will all have a *user* and a *group*.  Could you add them to your question?

Comment: It's a temporary file so I can't be sure as it doesn't exists after this error is produced however the non-temporary version of the file has these permissions: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6662

Comment: The directory `/var/www/awstats` has permissions.

Comment: That comes up as drwxrwxr-x 9 root root

Answer (score 2):

The permissions `drwxrwxr-x root root` mean that only the `root` user and members of the `root` group can write to that directory.  Creating or deleting files within a directory is considered to be *writing* to that directory so the permissions checks are done against the containing directory when you try to create the file `/var/www/awstats/awstats032014.site.net.tmp.9198`.

The other half of this problem is that it is Apache that is doing the creating of files.  Apache usually runs as the `www-data` user on Debian based systems and as `httpd` on RedHat based systems.  These users are not in the `root` group and so cannot write to that directory.

The principle of least privilege suggests that we should make a change that allows just what we want and no more.  So I think changing the directory owner to the Apache user would do the job.

```
chown www-data /var/www/awstats
```

You can also change the mode back to `755` from `775` if you want and it will still work.

Instead of changing the ownership, you could change the group of the directory, or add the `www-data` user to the `root` group, or change the mode of the directory to 777.  The latter two allow much more than just what we're trying to do here and hence should be considered dangerous.

Comment: this fixed half my problem, but I still had to run as sudo to get it to work